# `imagesc` in MATLAB: paper size and `colorbar`

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I am using `imagesc` in MATLAB to show an `NxM` matrix as an image, where the warmer is the color the higher is the value. By using the following command:

```
f = imagesc(points, [0 1]);
```

the matrix `points` is displayed. Nevertheless, a legend showing the coupling between colors and values is missing. I have found out that the command:

```
colorbar
```

can be used so as to display the requested legend. However, when printing the figure on PDF using the following lines of code:

```
set(gcf, 'PaperUnits', 'centimeters')
set(gcf,'PaperSize',[12 8]) % Set the paper size to the figure size
print('-dpdf',figurePath)
```

I encounter two problems:

- The paper size is not set properly
- The color bar is not showing on the PDF

How can I fix these problems?

Thanks in advance,

Eleanore.

Comment: Have you changed the `PaperUnits` property? By default, it's in inches, which might explain why the paper size isn't set properly and maybe also why the colour bar isn't showing (off the paper).

Comment: Yes, I'm changing it to centimeters. Still, it doesn't fix the problem. I'll update the question body according to your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution in the state of the art, that uses the `export_fig` script (https://sites.google.com/site/oliverwoodford/software/export_fig).

The following code is needed:

```
set(gcf, 'Color', 'w');                     % Change background color
set(gcf, 'Position', [100 100 700 500])     % Change figure dimensions
export_fig([figurePath '.pdf'])             % Export the figure
```

Answer (score 0):

I always export my figures to `.eps` and then use the [`epstopdf`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/epstopdf) utility that comes with Ghostscript to convert for inclusion in a LaTeX document; this seems to solve the vast majority of issues.

Another way to do it is to use the [export_fig](https://sites.google.com/site/oliverwoodford/software/export_fig) script, but I see you've already discovered that.